# What's the degree of obligation of the first Biur Halacha (in MB 1:1)?

Tags: halacha, mishnah-berurah

It says that we're supposed to recite different lines before each of  the three prayers.  My question is: is it halacha?  why does the Chafetz Chaim bring it if it is not?  What does the lashon "nachon m'od lizaher" mean if it's NOT an obligation?  What language would be used if it WAS an obligation?

I'm confused.

---

Beur Halacha

> שיהא הוא מעורר השחר - **נכון מאד ליזהר לומר קודם כל ג' תפלות הודאת
>   היה"ר** המבואר בירושלמי פ' תפלת השחר דהיינו:‏
>
> 1. בשחרית מודה אני לפניך ד' או"א שהוצאתני מאפלה לאורה.‏
> 2. ובמנחה מודה אני וכו' שכשם שזיכיתני לראות כשהחמה במזרח כך זכיתי לראותה במערב.‏
> 3. בערבית יה"ר כו' כשם שהייתי באפילה והוצאתני לאורה כן תוציאני מאפילה לאורה:‏

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi

Comment: I wondered myself how obligatory this was and who actually said it. These lines appear in my siddur (which follows MB)

Comment: Just because the Mishnah Berurah says it doesn't necessarily mean it was accepted by Klal Yisrael as halacha.

Comment: @DonielF that's kinda my question: how do we know if something has been accepted by klal yisroel?  One would have thought that "be very careful to say" would be an indicator...no?

Comment: @MarkZelunka That just indicates that the Mishnah Berurah felt it was appropriate, not that anyone else agreed. You’d have to check later works to see what they have to say on the matter.